# How to select all objects that match all the ids in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of ingredients ids and I need to find all recipes that contains all the ingredients together and not one or any of the ingredients.

I tried something like this:

```
var query = (from ri in db.RecipesIngredients
                     where SelectedIDs.Contains(ri.IngredientId)
                     select ri.RecipeId).Distinct();
```

This acts as: get recipes that contains id1 or id2 or id3 etc.. i want it to be: get recipes that contain id1 and id2 and id3 etc..

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a table Recipe in your table?

Comment: Do you need the recipe to include *all* selected ingredients - or just *not* include any ingredients which aren't selected?

Comment: Yes there's a Recipes table and I need to get the recipes that include all selected ingredients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close:

```
var query = (from r in db.Recipes
                     where SelectedIDs.All(i => r.Ingredients.Any(ri => ri.IngredientId == i))
                     select r.RecipeId).Distinct();
```

Translated as

"Give me all of the recipes where all of the ingredients in `SelectedIDs` are in that recipe's list of ingredients."

Comment: Well it's working but I can't understand what you've done here, would you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* you actually want all the recipes which don't include any unselected ingredients, in which case you might use:

```
var query = db.RecipesIngredients
              .Except(db.RecipeIngredients
                        .Where(x => SelectedIDs.Contains(x.IngredientId)))
              .Select(ri => ri.RecipeId);
```

I believe that makes *logical* sense - whether it translates into SQL or not is a different matter.

If you really *do* want a recipe which includes all the selected ingredients (but may also include other unselected ingredients) then D Stanley's answer is probably what you're after.

Comment: Yes I want all recipes that include all selected ingredients and may also include other unselected ingredients.